# Prevent auto-start up of application that doesn't have a native setting to disable it

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, printer

I install some software for my printer. The problem is that is that is auto starts with my computer. I checked the application settings but it doesn't have a way to disable it. Is there another way I can prevent this application from starting on it's own? I would ideally like to do this without install more software.

Comment: For an application to start there must be an entry somewhere. Either in the users "Start, all programs, startup" folder, the global startup folder or in the registry. Check the two startup folders. If it is not there, either look for the 'run' keys in the registry or use something like ccleaner to show those keys (depending on your skill).

Answer (score 2):

### Startup folder

As [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes) suggested, you can try looking in the `Startup` folder. Delete any unwanted programs in that folder, and they won't start during boot.
(my experience is that hardly any programs place themselves there, though, so the following methods will probably have a bigger chance of success)

### msconfig

1. Open the "Run" prompt: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `msconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Go to the Startup tab and untick the appropriate box.
4. Press `OK` to save the changes

### [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

If `msconfig` doesn't work for some reason, or if the program isn't listed in `msconfig`, you can try Microsoft's Sysinternals `Autoruns`

It's similar to `msconfig` (but way more complicated), there are boxes next to every entry which you can deselect if you don't want them to start with Windows.
There are also some crucial system items that you can disable, thus breaking your system, so only use it when you know what you're doing. ***Don't randomly uncheck items.***

Answer (score 0):

Is your software one of the "printer support" bloatware packages that are installed automatically for many printers if you use the default installation from the CD? HP in particular is a massive offender here.

In that case, uninstall the printer, and then install the driver only.

Comment: No, its a canon printer. But I assume it is equally as bloated.